# MySQL Join latest event only, slow when table over 16 records

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a list of servers in my database, along with a table of server events.  I want to query for the servers along with the time they were last restarted.

```sql
SELECT
  s.server_name,
  e.event_message,
  e.timestamp as last_restart
FROM servers s
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.id=(
  SELECT e.id
  FROM events e
  WHERE
    (e.`server_id`=s.id) AND
    (e.`event-type`='restart')
  ORDER BY e.timestamp
  LIMIT 1
);
```

The query works, but it's slow when servers are greater than 18:

- 16 servers: query takes <0.1s
- 17 servers: query takes ~0.5s
- 18 servers: query takes >1.0s

These numbers seem to grow proportionally to the size of the events table.  If I delete the servers in my table back down to 16, the queries are fast again.

Questions

1. Events has an index on event-type, an index on server_id, an index on timestamp, an index on ID, and a composite index on server_id and event_type.  Servers has an index on id.  Are different / more indexes needed?
2. It appears that MySQL (v5.6.x) is changing how the query is executed depending on how many rows are in the server table.  What is this magic limit?  Is there a way to force execution to what is working faster?
3. Is there a better way to structure this query?

Notes:

1. There may be multiple events for the server at the same timestamp, so joining by the timestamp alone isn't unique.
2. I cannot update MySQL.

Comment: Please post schema, EXPLAIN results and sample data, that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you pls share the explains for both the slow and the fast run of your query?

Comment: This is a single question really: how can I optimise my query. All the points are just different aspects of optimisation. Btw, there is no magic limit.

Comment: You need this index: `events(server_id, event_type, timestamp)` if `id` is PK.